# Add content to iframe with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, iframe, beautifulsoup

Let say I have the following iframe

```
 s=""""
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">         
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
 </iframe>

 </body>
 </html>
 """
```

I want to replace all content with this string 'this is the replacement'
If I use

```
dom = BeatifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
f = dom.find('iframe')
f.contents[0].replace_with('this is the replacement')
```

Then instead of replacing all the content I will replace only the first character, which in this case is a newline. Also this does not work if the iframe is completely empty because f.contents[0] is out of index

Comment: Do you want to replace the entire content in `iframe` tag?

Comment: yes, but not destroy the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the [`.string` property](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
 </iframe>

 </body>
 </html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
frame = soup.iframe

frame.string = 'this is the replacement'

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
   this is the replacement
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you aware of any way that I can do that even if the replacement is not just a string?

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee do you mean the repl string is actually an HTML snippet?

Comment: yes, I opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891983/how-to-add-outer-tag-to-beautifulsoup-object) relating to that

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you to replace the `iframe` tag content.

```
s="""
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
 </iframe>
 </body>
 </html>
 """
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
show= soup.findAll('iframe')[0]
show.replaceWith('<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">this is the replacement</iframe>'.encode('utf-8'))
html = HTMLParser()
print html.unescape(str(soup.prettify()))
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">my text</iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was looking for a way that I wouldn't have to create the tag again, are you aware of something like that?