# How to add outer tag to BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, html, iframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to replace the content of an iframe a BeautifulSoup object. Let say this

```
 s="""
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">         
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
 </iframe>

 </body>
 </html>
 """
```

is the original html being parsed with

```
dom = BeatifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
```

and I get the iframe with `f = dom.find('iframe')`

Now I want to replace only the content of the iframe with another BeautifulSoup object, eg the object newBO. If I do `f.replace_with(newBO)`
it works but I lose the hierarchy of the original file because the iframe tag is gone. If instead of a BeautifulSoup object I had just a string I could do `f.string = 'just a string'` and that would replace the content, but if I do `f.string = newBO`

I get

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

So I am trying to use the `replace_with` but add an `iframe` tag to the newBO. How can I do that? Can you suggest some other way?

Comment: You can use `get_text()` function to return contents beneath a tag-- `f.get_text().replace_with(newBO)`. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa, text has nothing to do with tags. `get_text -> Your browser does not support iframes.` so that would not do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*extract*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) the content then [insert](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
dom = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

f = dom.find('iframe')
for ele in f.find_all():
    ele.extract()
new = BeautifulSoup("<div>foo</div>").find("div")
f.insert(0, new)
print(dom)
```

Which would give you:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"><div>foo</div>

</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

To also remove any string set `f.string=""`:

```
f = dom.find('iframe')

for ele in f.find_all():
    print(type(ele))
    ele.extract()
f.string = ""
new = BeautifulSoup("<div>foo</div>","html.parser").find("div")
f.insert(0, new)
print(dom)
```

Which would then give you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"><div>foo</div></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case you could also use `f.append(new)` as it is going to be the only element.

Comment: The example you provided works, but for some reason when I am trying to apply it in my problem I get some weird results. I have stored a soup object in a dictionary, if I follow the exact above procedure but instead of `new` I use the object that I have stored in my dom dictionary, like `f.insert(0, dom[1]`) I get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'`. Basically every function of `f` that I will try to call with this argument I will get this response, any idea what may be going wrong?

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee. that error stems from calls like `f = dom.find('iframe')` returning None , are you sure the code is finding the tags you expect?

Comment: I just realized that it's not finding the elements I am looking for, thnks for the help